# getting error " ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable " while using send_key() function in python selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

i have tried CSS selector to send value using send_key() function in search box and submit that so that i get the table list of doctors on particular year , but getting below error 
    " ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable "

below is the code which i have written :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

url = "https://www.mciindia.org/CMS/information-desk/indian-medical-register"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Year of Registration')]").click()
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("input[type='text']")[-1].send_keys("2015")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='Submit']").click()

next_page = True
while next_page == True:
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    table1 = soup.find('table',{'id':'doct_info2'})
    try:
        rows = table1.find_all('tr')

        for row in rows:
            if len(row.find_all('td')) == 7:
                data = row.find_all('td')

                link = data[6].click()

                soup2 = bs(link, 'html.parser')
                table2 = soup2.find('table',{'id':'doctorBiodata'})
                rows = table2.find_all('tr')
                print(rows)
    except:
         pass

    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]").click()
    except:
        print ('No more pages')
        next_page=False

driver.close()
```

Comment: do you want the entire search result of `2015` ? and the entire data of each `doctor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is for the first `10` result.

You can change `length` from `10` to `42354` which is the maximum for year `2015` and you will get file of `out.csv` in same second.

And the second file which is `data.csv` will include the internal doctor details.

The page is rendered via `JavaScript` so I've located the `XHR` request under `Network-Table` from your Browser `Developer-Tools`. which is `JS` .

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import re
import requests


def Table():
    table = pd.read_json("https://mciindia.org/MCIRest/open/getPaginatedData?service=getPaginatedDoctor&draw=1&columns[0][data]=0&columns[0][name]=&columns[0][searchable]=true&columns[0][orderable]=true&columns[0][search][value]=&columns[0][search][regex]=false&columns[1][data]=1&columns[1][name]=&columns[1][searchable]=true&columns[1][orderable]=true&columns[1][search][value]=&columns[1][search][regex]=false&columns[2][data]=2&columns[2][name]=&columns[2][searchable]=true&columns[2][orderable]=true&columns[2][search][value]=&columns[2][search][regex]=false&columns[3][data]=3&columns[3][name]=&columns[3][searchable]=true&columns[3][orderable]=true&columns[3][search][value]=&columns[3][search][regex]=false&columns[4][data]=4&columns[4][name]=&columns[4][searchable]=true&columns[4][orderable]=true&columns[4][search][value]=&columns[4][search][regex]=false&columns[5][data]=5&columns[5][name]=&columns[5][searchable]=true&columns[5][orderable]=true&columns[5][search][value]=&columns[5][search][regex]=false&columns[6][data]=6&columns[6][name]=&columns[6][searchable]=true&columns[6][orderable]=true&columns[6][search][value]=&columns[6][search][regex]=false&order[0][column]=0&order[0][dir]=asc&start=0&length=10&search[value]=&search[regex]=false&year=2015&_=1577626804003")['data']
    with open('out.csv', 'w', newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(
            ['Year Of The Info', 'Registration#', 'State Medical Councils', 'Name', 'FatherName'])
        data = []
        for item in table:
            writer.writerow(item[1:6])
            required = item[6]
            match = re.search(
                r"openDoctorDetailsnew\('([^']*)', '([^']*)'", required)
            data.append(match.group().split("'")[1:4:2])
        print("Data Saved Into out.csv")
    return data


def Details():
    names = []
    items = []
    for doc, val in Table():
        print(f"Extracting DoctorID# {doc}, RegValue# {val}")
        json = {'doctorId': doc, 'regdNoValue': val}
        r = requests.post(
            "https://mciindia.org/MCIRest/open/getDataFromService?service=getDoctorDetailsByIdImr", json=json).json()
        if r.keys() not in names:
            names.append(r.keys())
        items.append(r.values())
    print("Done")
    return names, items


def Save():
    with open('data.csv', 'w', newline="") as d:
        writer = csv.writer(d)
        n, i = Details()
        writer.writerows(n)
        writer.writerows(i)


Save()
```

Check Output Sample [out.csv](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/64288fdb6ba483258db2034893cd004c/out.csv) And [data.csv](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/e64642cd1cc053f8faf9a11adf853ecf/data.csv)

> Note: you have to take a look on `concurrent.futures` in case if you will do huge scrape for internal data.

Comment: @NiteshRao :) you welcome . it was very interesting task for me

Comment: can you please add comments in above code , so that i can understand your code , as i dont know how json works in python and from where you take that " "table = pd.read_json(above_link) " and  post link

Comment: getting this error  " Invalid octet in UTF-8 sequence when decoding 'string'  " how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

To Enter value on the textbox You need to Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and use `send_keys`()

To get the table you need to induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for table to be visible `visibility_of_element_located`()

**Code**:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import time

url = "https://www.mciindia.org/CMS/information-desk/indian-medical-register"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[text()='Year of Registration']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='doctor_year']"))).send_keys("2015")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@id='doctor_year_details']"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"table.table.table-bordered.dataTable.no-footer")))

next_page = True
while next_page == True:
    soup = bs(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    table1 = soup.find('table',{'id':'doct_info2'})
    try:
        rows = table1.find_all('tr')

        for row in rows:
            if len(row.find_all('td')) == 7:
                data = row.find_all('td')

                link = data[6].click()

                soup2 = bs(link, 'html.parser')
                table2 = soup2.find('table',{'id':'doctorBiodata'})
                rows = table2.find_all('tr')
                print(rows)
    except:
         pass

    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Next')]").click()
    except:
        print ('No more pages')
        next_page=False

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do whole thing more quickly with just requests. Change the draw param to get different pages. You can dynamically add or remove the timestamp param '_'. Change 'year'for a different year. The initial json response gives a record count so it is easy enough to calculate the end count for a loop over all results in batches of 500. Use `Session` object for efficiency of tcp connection re-use with multiple requests in loop.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

params = (
    ('service', 'getPaginatedDoctor'),
    ('draw', '1'),
    ('columns[0][data]', '0'),
    ('columns[0][name]', ''),
    ('columns[0][searchable]', 'true'),
    ('columns[0][orderable]', 'true'),
    ('columns[0][search][value]', ''),
    ('columns[0][search][regex]', 'false'),
    ('columns[1][data]', '1'),
    ('columns[1][name]', ''),
    ('columns[1][searchable]', 'true'),
    ('columns[1][orderable]', 'true'),
    ('columns[1][search][value]', ''),
    ('columns[1][search][regex]', 'false'),
    ('columns[2][data]', '2'),
    ('columns[2][name]', ''),
    ('columns[2][searchable]', 'true'),
    ('columns[2][orderable]', 'true'),
    ('columns[2][search][value]', ''),
    ('columns[2][search][regex]', 'false'),
    ('columns[3][data]', '3'),
    ('columns[3][name]', ''),
    ('columns[3][searchable]', 'true'),
    ('columns[3][orderable]', 'true'),
    ('columns[3][search][value]', ''),
    ('columns[3][search][regex]', 'false'),
    ('columns[4][data]', '4'),
    ('columns[4][name]', ''),
    ('columns[4][searchable]', 'true'),
    ('columns[4][orderable]', 'true'),
    ('columns[4][search][value]', ''),
    ('columns[4][search][regex]', 'false'),
    ('columns[5][data]', '5'),
    ('columns[5][name]', ''),
    ('columns[5][searchable]', 'true'),
    ('columns[5][orderable]', 'true'),
    ('columns[5][search][value]', ''),
    ('columns[5][search][regex]', 'false'),
    ('columns[6][data]', '6'),
    ('columns[6][name]', ''),
    ('columns[6][searchable]', 'true'),
    ('columns[6][orderable]', 'true'),
    ('columns[6][search][value]', ''),
    ('columns[6][search][regex]', 'false'),
    ('order[0][column]', '0'),
    ('order[0][dir]', 'asc'),
    ('start', '0'),
    ('length', '500'),
    ('search[value]', ''),
    ('search[regex]', 'false'),
    ('name', ''),
    ('registrationNo', ''),
    ('smcId', ''),
    ('year', '2015'),
    ('_', '1577634512046'),
)

table_headers = ['Sl. No.','Year of Info','Registration Number','State Medical Councils','Name','Father Name','Action']
r = requests.get('https://mciindia.org/MCIRest/open/getPaginatedData',  params=params)
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['data'], columns = table_headers)
print(df)
```

Comment: check my answer

Comment: I've done the code around 2 hours ago but was checking `TCP` dump in order to hit internal doctor details in one time. actually the `OP` doing the full round for the internal doctor details which you can view by clicking on `View` button.

Comment: tbh I didn't bother playing with params but looks like you can probably remove quite a few

Comment: yea the empty values can be off. but for the internal table. it's different http://www.sharecsv.com/s/e64642cd1cc053f8faf9a11adf853ecf/data.csv